# Golang amazon s3 video upload giving weird errors

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I am using Golang as my backend code, I have an app that allows people to upload images and videos. I have images working and videos used to work but now for some reason I am getting this error which is the same as this one https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/15 . I have checked and the video is crossing over since the file that is being returned has some size but for some reason I keep getting the error below when it comes to uploading videos ... The error occurs in the **PutObject** below any suggestions would be great

```
func UploadStreamVideo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("us-west-2"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, ""),
    })

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        log_errors("HomePage-UploadStreamImage: error receiving file", err.Error(), w)
        fmt.Println("Error Uploading Image")
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    println(handler.Filename) // I can see filename
    println(handler.Size)   // I also see the size here

    read_file, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)

    if err != nil {
        log_errors("HomePage-UploadStreamImage")
        return
    }

    file.Read(read_file)
    fileBytes := bytes.NewReader(read_file)
    fileSize, err := buf.ReadFrom(file)
    if err != nil {
        log_errors("HomePage-UploadStreamImage")
    }

    fileType := http.DetectContentType(read_file)
    path := handler.Filename

    params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("yisl"),
        Key:    aws.String(path),
        Body:   fileBytes,

        ContentLength: aws.Int64(fileSize),
        ContentType:   aws.String(fileType),
    }

     // This code below gives the error
    _, err = svc.PutObject(params)
    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        log_errors("HomePage-UploadStreamImage")
        return
    }

    io.WriteString(w, "Done")
}
```

And the error:

```
NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is
not implemented     status code: 501, request id: 310D0CE7643E1B4B, host
id:
GUB8UDi9KJTIPybXh3I1m5Vu8Ixyt4LQv5PbVnyOH2ngAdtOv0DsyALHp1mMI3SmRpK+xHV3uds=

> 2018/05/12 03:30:21 http: panic serving [::1]:64945: runtime error:
> invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine 10
> [running]: net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc420229400)
>   /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0xd0 panic(0x1451b20,
> 0x1752c30)    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:502 +0x229
> database/sql.(*Rows).close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
>   /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2907 +0x6b
> database/sql.(*Rows).Close(0x0, 0x14f5698, 0x4d)
>   /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2903 +0x33
> _/Users/ignaciohernandez/Documents/go/Yisly-Backend/Controllers.log_errors(0x14ef38b,
> 0x2e, 0xc42010aa80, 0xda, 0x15737c0, 0xc420244380)
>   /Users/ignaciohernandez/Documents/go/Yisly-Backend/Controllers/function_store.go:27
> +0x2d8
> _/Users/ignaciohernandez/Documents/go/Yisly-Backend/Controllers.UploadStreamVideo(0x15737c0,
> 0xc420244380, 0xc420211700)
>   /Users/ignaciohernandez/Documents/go/Yisly-Backend/Controllers/HomePage.go:377
> +0x7ad net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x14fd130, 0x15737c0, 0xc420244380, 0xc420211700)   /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1947
> +0x44 github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc420142380, 0x15737c0, 0xc420244380, 0xc420211700)
>   /Users/ignaciohernandez/Documents/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:162
> +0xed net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x1760f20, 0x15737c0, 0xc420244380, 0xc420211500)    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2337
> +0x130 net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc4201c89c0, 0x15737c0, 0xc420244380, 0xc420211500)  /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2694
> +0xbc net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc420229400, 0x1573b40, 0xc42002c9c0)   /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1830 +0x651 created by
> net/http.(*Server).Serve  /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2795
> +0x27b
```

Comment: Your error message is a bit confusing. Is that exactly how you see it appearing?  Or is that two errors (an error, followed by a stack trace)?

Comment: As @Flimzy said, the whole thing is a bit confusing. So my advise is to start cleaning things a little bit from the start.

First, you `ioutil.ReadAll`, after it you `file.Read` (but since you ioutil.ReadAll the cursor is at the very end so you should be getting no bytes).

You don't need to do that process to get the file size because you already have `handler.Size`.

Comment: Looking at the AWS S3 documentation of PutObject (link below) the `Body` is a `io.ReadSeeker` and the `multipart.File` you get when you `r.FormFile("file")` implements `io.Reader` and `io.Seeker` so I think you can pass `file` direct to the `PutObject`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#PutObjectInput